# Todas as tabs aparecendo ao atualizar pagina materialize

Tags: html, jquery, css, materialize

Alguém sabe por que isso acontece ? Quando eu atualizo a página aparece uma parte das tabs seguintes e depois desaparece quando termina de carregar. Quero evitar que isso aconteça.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
<section class="section-cadastro blue-grey darken-4 z-depth-5 row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <h4>Escolha o tipo de cadastro</h4>
        <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-1">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-2">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-3">Test 3</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-4">Test 4</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-5">Test 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 normal-user">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col l6 m6 s12">
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="first_name">Primeiro Nome</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col l6 m6 s12">
                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="last_name">Segundo Nome</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                        <label for="password">Senha</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="confirm_password" type="password" class="validate">
                        <label for="confirm_password">Confirmar Senha</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cad-select input-field col l4 m6 s12">
                        <select>
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Função </option>
                          <option value="1">Compositor</option>
                          <option value="2">Cantor</option>
                          <option value="3">Bateirista</option>
                           <option value="4"></option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Escolha sua Função</label>
                    </div>                  

                    <div class="cad-select input-field col l4 m6 s12">
                        <select>
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Instrumento </option>
                          <option value="1">Gaita</option>
                          <option value="2">Violino</option>
                          <option value="3">Violão</option>
                          <option value="4">Bateria</option>
                          <option value="5"></option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Escolha seu Instrumento</label>
                    </div>      
                </div>                                                          

                <div class="cad-select input-field col s12 center">
                    <a class="blue btn btn-login">
                       Cadastrar-se
                    </a> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 red">Test 2</div>
        <div id="test-swipe-3" class="col s12 blue">Test 3</div>
        <div id="test-swipe-4" class="col s12 green">Test 4</div>
        <div id="test-swipe-5" class="col s12 grey">Test 5</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.section-cadastro .tabs-content.carousel .carousel-item{ 
    height: 550px;
}
.section-cadastro{
    padding: 0px 10px 30px 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.section-cadastro.row{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.section-cadastro > .col{
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monroe se vc reparar no próprio site do Materialize se vc der um <kbd>F5</kbd> na documentação das Tabs vc vai ver que até lá esse Bug aparece. http://materializecss.com/tabs.html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu reparei que se vc colocar todos os CDNs do Materialize com `rel="preload"` no `<head>` da página vai ter uma pequena melhora. Mas infelizmente mesmo sendo 150ms ainda da para ver as cores piscando

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script rel="preload" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" as="script"></script>
<script rel="preload" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js" as="script"></script>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas nem tudo está perdido. Com CSS a gente pode adiantar um comportamento desse componete de Tabs do Materialize. Repare na imagem que ele coloca um     `display:none;` em todas as abas que não estão ativas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A forma que eu consegui para esse Bug sumir é me adiantar e colocar na mão mesmo esses `display:none;` ao ter que esperar a página carregar todos os JS para que isso aconteça.

**Veja que nesse Snippet o Bug não aparece e as Tabs funcionam normalmente**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <script rel="preload" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" as="script"></script>
    <script rel="preload" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js" as="script"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    
    .section-cadastro .tabs-content.carousel .carousel-item{ 
    height: 550px;
    }
    .section-cadastro{
        padding: 0px 10px 30px 10px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .section-cadastro.row{
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    .section-cadastro > .col{
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<section class="section-cadastro blue-grey darken-4 z-depth-5 row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <h4>Escolha o tipo de cadastro</h4>
        <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
            <li class="tab col s2"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-1">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s2"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-2">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s2"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-3">Test 3</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s2"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-4">Test 4</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s2"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-5">Test 5</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s2"><a class="indicator-custom" href="#test-swipe-6">Test 6</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 normal-user">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col l6 m6 s12">
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="first_name">Primeiro Nome</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col l6 m6 s12">
                        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="last_name">Segundo Nome</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                        <label for="password">Senha</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <input id="confirm_password" type="password" class="validate">
                        <label for="confirm_password">Confirmar Senha</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cad-select input-field col l4 m6 s12">
                        <select>
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Função </option>
                          <option value="1">Compositor</option>
                          <option value="2">Cantor</option>
                          <option value="3">Bateirista</option>
                           <option value="4"></option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Escolha sua Função</label>
                    </div>                  

                    <div class="cad-select input-field col l4 m6 s12">
                        <select>
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Instrumento </option>
                          <option value="1">Gaita</option>
                          <option value="2">Violino</option>
                          <option value="3">Violão</option>
                          <option value="4">Bateria</option>
                          <option value="5"></option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Escolha seu Instrumento</label>
                    </div>      
                </div>                                                          

                <div class="cad-select input-field col s12 center">
                    <a class="blue btn btn-login">
                       Cadastrar-se
                    </a> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 red" style="display: none">Test 2</div>
        <div id="test-swipe-3" class="col s12 blue" style="display: none">Test 3</div>
        <div id="test-swipe-4" class="col s12 green" style="display: none">Test 4</div>
        <div id="test-swipe-5" class="col s12 grey" style="display: none">Test 5</div>
        <div id="test-swipe-6" class="col s12 red" style="display: none">Test 6</div>

    </div>
</section>
    
</body>
</html>
```